# Convert html request to ajax request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one action of which it is looking for html page but I want to make it to look js.erb file. I'm on ruby on rails. Is this possible??

Comment: it is possible, add `:remote => true` to the link

Comment: i'm not looking that one .. i want to convert it in controller level. It is looking for .html.erb file, instead of that it has to look for .js.erb file, from the controller i want to change